# iPhone ScrollView and Picker Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I noticed an strange issue with my application that only occurs on the iPhone 3G and iPhone 3GS.  I am creating a scroll view with two pages.  On the second page of the scroll, when you try to scroll the picker, it is very unresponsive.  It kinda appears that my application can't distinguish between the scrolling of the picker and the scrolling of the scrollview, because sometimes you scroll up and it goes to the left.

Please keep in mind, this works great on the iPhone 4 and iPhone 4S.

Has anyone ran into this problem before or any idea of what is actually going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the UIScrollView and UIPickerView cause problems if used together.  However, this only occurred on the iPhone 3 and iPhone 3GS.

The solution was to subclass UIScrollView and implement the following method.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point 
         withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView *result = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    if ([result.superview isKindOfClass:[UIPickerView class]]) {
        self.canCancelContentTouches = NO;  
        self.delaysContentTouches = NO;
    }
    else {
        self.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
        self.delaysContentTouches = YES;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only enable armv7 in your build settings (not armv6), that's all

Comment: That's weard. Once my app wasn't working on 3G. After adding armv6 it was compatible... Sorry that I can't help you any further

Comment: iPhone 3G is amrv6 that is why

Answer (score 0):

Add a UIView over scroll view, over UIView add UIPickerView.

Comment: I add a view with the picker to the scroll view, and this is not working, just on 3G/3GS